# SMS gateway is not working when server changed

Tags: webserver, amazon-web-services, sms

I am using aws server with 2 instances one say "x" and another as "y" and using ibox sms gateway. Previously I was using server x for my work and also integrated sms gateway in it. All was working good. But now I am using server y for my work with same code used on server x, but sms gateway is not working. Tried again on server x but it is working condition, but in y it not works. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Not working" is too vague, you need to do some diagnostics / problem solving. You should look into security groups and network ACLs to see if they're blocking connectivity to the gateway. The gateway may only accept data from a specific IP address. You could ping the gateway from both machines to see if there's a problem, but ping ICMP is often blocked and may not give useful information.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Security groups of both the server's.
Still it exits use the AMI of first server and launch the same server as a server2.

Why am saying this is , may be you changed the configuration while installing the sms gateway in the server 2.

Thanks,